# While importing data from Excel getting error for timestamp field in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

sample data:- 14-JUN-19 03.39.26.000000000 PM
while importing from excel getting an error like "Insert failed for row  1
CREATED_TS GDK-05058: non-numeric character found UPDATED_TS GDK-05058: non-numeric character found".
DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SSXFF AM
And then i tried to modify NLS value "Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS" but no use.
Can someone suggest the exact format for this?

[Data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rfH7.png)

Comment: Can you specify the database you are working with?

Comment: While importing, if you have any date column, please provide the format of the date

Comment: What tool/IDE and method are you using to import the data? Whatever it is, if you changed preferences, did you then start a new session? It's better not to rely on NLS settings but without know what you are doing we can't say how to improve your process. (Also, use 4-digit years, or if you can't change the date, at least use RR instead of YY.)

Comment: I'm trying to import data using SQL developer